# remove string between two occurance of a string in file name

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to Linux and I have to remove a specific string of digits in a file name.

Here are my file names:

```
AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.INSERT.123.20130315.CSV 
AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.APPEND.5345667.20130315.CSV
```

I need the output as:

```
AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.INSERT.20130315.CSV   
AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.APPEND.20130315.CSV
```

I want to remove the `123` and which may `5345667` or other numbers what ever come in that position, so I want to remove string between . (5th occurrence) and . (6th Occurrence) in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

`cut` can do this:

```
pax> echo 'AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.INSERT.123.20130315.CSV' | cut -d. -f1-5,7-
AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.INSERT.20130315.CSV

pax> echo 'AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.APPEND.5345667.20130315.CSV' | cut -d. -f1-5,7-
AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.APPEND.20130315.CSV
```

The `-d.` simply sets the delimiter to `.` and the `-f1-5,7-` gives you all fields except the sixth one.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response, I actually need to rename all files in a dir . could you please help me how to rename the file  using this cut command

Comment: @Naga, if you want to rename files, you should look into `prename` (sometimes `rename`) - it's meant for just that purpose, giving you the full regex capabilies of Perl to rename files. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292232/rename-batch-of-file-in-unix/12292263#12292263 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138322/script-to-change-basename-with-without-changing-extension-in-linux/10138364#10138364

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I have created the below script to rename the file.                                                    #!/bin/sh
for i in `ls -a *.CSV`
do
echo "$i"
newFileName=$( echo "$i" | cut -d. -f1-5,7-)
echo $newFileName
mv $i $newFileName
done

Answer (score 0):

**Input.txt**

```
AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.INSERT.123.20130315.CSV 
AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.APPEND.5345667.20130315.CSV
```

**Command**

```
awk -F "." '{ $6=""; print $0 }' Input.txt | sed -e 's/ /\./g' -e 's/\.\./\./g'
```

**Output**

```
AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.INSERT.20130315.CSV   
AB.TEXT.OMN.BUFFER.APPEND.20130315.CSV
```